# There is a code snippet in my PHP script that fetches certain properties for a userID using an API call

Tags: php

There is a code snippet in my PHP script that fetches certain properties for a userID using an API call.

Some of the userIDs do not have certain fields. Like every user might not have an owner. So, that field does not return anything and I get the following when I run the script in browser:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

This is fine for me as the code still executes further.

When I run the same script through a cron, I get a fatal error and the script's execution stops. How can I run the script exactly as it is running in the browser so that I do not get the fatal error?

---

## Solved

This is what works for me:

cd /home/####/public_html/####/; /usr/local/bin/php -c -f file.php

"cd /home/####/public_html/####/;" changes the directory to where my "file.php" is located. Can anyone let me know why the above command works and the following does not:
cd /home/####/public_html/####/; /usr/local/bin/php file.php

Comment: Can your code just check if an object is null before trying to use it?

Comment: I would not be able to make a change in the script. I am running a cron in the cpanel and am more concerned about why it works in the browser and not while I am running it by setting up a cron.

Comment: cron will use the cli, which may be different than the interpreter used by the web server.

Comment: What's the error message you're getting in the CLI?

Comment: It will involve a little more overhead, but if you really have to, you could have cron make a wget call to the PHP page's URL.

Answer (score -1):

Solution 1, if you can change the script:

You can check to ensure that the var is set before you fill it.  For example:

```
$name = "";
if (isset($var['name'])) {
    $name = $var['name'];
}
```

Thats the best example I could give without a code sample...  You might also be able to get away with the @ error suppression, but Im not sure how well it works with var assignments.

UPDATE:

The @ error suppression worked in a quick cli test on my mac:

```
@$name = $var['name'];
```

The @ sign tells the interpreter to suppress errors on that line and continue.  While this works, the first example is cleaner.

---

Solution 2, if you cannot update the script:

Change the cron to run the script through curl/wget.  Put the script in a location where it can be called through the server (even an internal-only vhost), and call it through curl/wget.  The other interpreter will be used as opposed to the CLI.